# Ассинхронная отправка файла на JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Приветствую всех.

Решил попробовать испытать возможности XMLHttpRequest2, в частности ассинхронную отправку файлов на сервер. И тут, как вы уже догадались, у меня начались проблемы.

Код формы отправки файла:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="load.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000">
  Отправить этот файл: 
  <input id="file" name="files[]" type="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Код JS:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  function uploadFiles(url, files) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) {
    formData.append(file.name, file);
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { 
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    uploadFiles('/load/load.php', this.files);
  }, false);
});
</script>
```

Код файла load.php:

```
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 3*1024*1024) {
  exit("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
}
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"])) {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/load/'.$_FILES["files"]["name"]);
  $file = stat($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/load/'.$_FILES["files"]["name"]);
  if($file) {
    echo 'Имя: '.$_FILES["files"]["name"].'<br>';
    echo 'Размер: '.$file['size'] / 1024 .' Кб<br>';
    echo 'Время последнего доступа: '.$file['atime'].'<br>';
    echo 'Время последней модификации: '.$file['mtime'].'<br>';
  }
} else {
   echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
}
```

При попытке отправить файл в качестве ответа приходит строка "Ошибка загрузки файла".
Прошу помощи у местных гуру :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.к. вы отправляете массив файлов (

```
name="files[]"
```

), то и приходит вам массив (

```
echo $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"];
// Array
```

). Думаю, логично, что "Array" вряд ли `is_uploaded_file` =)

Варианты:

- убрать [] из имени поля
- при получении либо юзать `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][0]`, либо обходить массив `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"]`.

На будущее - если код работает непонятно, в значимых местах порасставляйте такую конструкцию (ниже). В данном случае вряд ли пришлось бы задавать вопрос)

```
die(var_dump($var));
```

**UPD:** Я ни фига не понял, как это произошло, но... вот вам load.php) Код вообще не зависит от имени поля ввода - приходит что-то вроде `Array( "123_png" => Array( ... ) )` `o_O`

Код рабочий, проверил.

```
foreach ($_FILES as $f) {
  if($f["size"] > 3*1024*1024) {
    exit("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
  }
  if(is_uploaded_file($f["tmp_name"])) {
    move_uploaded_file($f["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/load/'.$f["name"]);
    $file = stat($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/load/'.$f["name"]);
    if($file) {
      echo 'Имя: '.$f["name"].'<br>';
      echo 'Размер: '.$file['size'] / 1024 .' Кб<br>';
      echo 'Время последнего доступа: '.$file['atime'].'<br>';
      echo 'Время последней модификации: '.$file['mtime'].'<br>';
    }
  } else {
     echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
  }
}
```

Comment: И да, посмотрите, что в `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` )) Прозреваю `NULL`)

Comment: К сожалению ни один из вариантов не работает. 
В $_FILES["file"]["size"] NULL((

Comment: @LightShock, дайте результат при посылке файла

    die(var_dump($_FILES["files"]));

Comment: Тоже NULL.

Comment: @LightShock, потестил на локалке и обновил ответ. Видимо, xhr2 как-то очень специфически файлы отправляет.

Comment: Работает!) Большое спасибо!)